# Laravel Rule::unique not working as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-6.2

This is my migration:

```php
Schema::create('coupons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
});
```

And this is my custom request:

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => [
            'required', 'string',
            Rule::unique('coupons')
            ->where(function ($q) {
                $q->where('name', 'OFFER-2020');
            })
    ]
}
```

I am trying to block requests where coupon `name` field already exists in database table. Since `OFFER-2020` row already exists in `coupons` table, it should block the request instead it passes validation.

**Update**
My input was `OFFER 2020`. And `OFFER-2020` is value after transformation. I thought laravel was checking unique with `OFFER-2020`. Instead it was checking with both `OFFER 2020` and `OFFER-2020` by a `and` query. And that's why my unique was not working.

Comment: Can you describe what validation you're actually trying to implement?

Comment: I am trying to block requests where coupon 'name' field already exists in database table

Comment: and please define what is not working? also how you use the rules either form request or inline validation should be included in teh question.

Comment: The input of name is OFFER-2020? you query does not make sense to have it static to be honest

Comment: but shouldn't it work? i have this 'name' in database table. why hard coded value would not work?

Comment: Does validation also fail (fail = no validation error) if you leave out the `Rule:` part and use string syntax? That is `['name' => ['unique:coupons']]`

Comment: The `Unique` rule works like this `Rule::unique(coupons)->ignore($id)`. Where `$id` is the current record id if you are modifying the record.

Comment: "but shouldn't it work? i have this 'name' in database table. why hard coded value would not work? " I know why it wont work, but i don't understand why you want to check unique against a hardcoded name, shouldnt the name be the input?

Comment: Sorry guys I wasted your time. Few seconds ago I put a wrong table name and i see this query in exception. Laravel unique always checks with it's requests input value + provided custom value
```select count(*) as aggregate from `columns` where `name` = OFFER 2020 and `name` = OFFER-2020```

Comment: @mrhn I was trying to provide modified value to unique rule. Looks like it's not possible

Comment: but if input is 'myname' then you will check that myname is not taken and name is OFFER-2020 which will never hold true? you are just avoiding the questions and saying it is not possible. Show me input, and what is expected right now your logic is flawed.

Comment: Please see my previous comment and it's query. My input is ```OFFER 2020```, My database table row is ```OFFER-2020```. I transform ```OFFER 2020``` to ```OFFER-2020``` and give it to ```Rule:unique```. I thought ```Rule:unique``` query would be ```select count(*) as aggregate from `coupons` where `name` = OFFER-2020``` but instead the query is ```select count(*) as aggregate from `coupons` where `name` = OFFER 2020 and `name` = OFFER-2020```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you input is `OFFER-2020`. You will only need to set the correct column name which is the second parameter of the unique rules. This will check the coupons table, for a row with the same name as the input.

```
Rule::unique('coupons', 'name')
```

To make your input slugified, you can utilise the form request method prepareForValidation(), this can transform your data.

```
function prepareForValidation() {
    $this->merge(['name' => Str::slug($this->get('name'))]);
}
```

Why did the previous version fail? As you can see here in the [Unique class](https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/7b8f65a7e783627552d292068afabd685fd6bffd/Rules/Unique.php#L39). If you do not provide a column it will default to id. So you previous query would end up looking something similar to this.

```
select * from coupons where id = 'OFFER-2020' and name = 'OFFER-2020'
```